# Accessing files in old computer hard drive

Tags: usb, hard-drive, ecryptfs

An old laptop with ubuntu 16.04 just died, i have extracted the hard drive and I’m using now a sata to usb cable to connect it to another laptop.
Windows doesn’t show anything, so I have mounted the new version of ubuntu on a usb drive and using “try ubuntu” I am able to mount the disk. My home directory has a red cross on it and looks empty, even though the disk is full. What are the next steps to access my data?
I have tried the ecryptfs commands but the answer is always command not found

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in *extended* support and supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: If you're using a *supported* Ubuntu product, you should provide details as no Ubuntu 14 exists or existed (Ubuntu's *specialist year* format releases didn't start until 2016, thus Ubuntu Core 16 was the first, the majority of products are *year.month* in format). You should also provide clear details as to what encryption was used; as Ubuntu's encryption defaults have changed, including the output from your actual command including the command itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you plug your old hard drive to another laptop ?

Ubuntu should adapt and boot normally.

Afterwards, you can transfer to an external hard drive, or use any other method to backup your data.

Most of times, the easiest method is the best choice.

Comment: I have just bought a mini laptop with a ssd, you are right, i should have bought a laptop with a hdd slot and plug it. Haven’t thought about that. F**k

Comment: @AlessandroIuculano You can use an inexpensive usb-to-sata adapter to do as the answerer suggests.